# Play youtube video in background

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am developing an Android app that suggests the most viewed videos clips in youtube, to play videos I am using the Youtube API for Android:

```
  @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    Log.d(TAG , "onInitializationSuccess(Provider, YouTubePlayer, boolean ) - Ini ");

    if(!b) {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID"));
    }

    Log.d(TAG , "onInitializationSuccess(Provider, YouTubePlayer, boolean ) - Fi ");

}
```

I would like to add an other feature to the app, I want to detect if the user is looking to the screen if not, I want to send the video to the background and keep playing the music, is this possible ?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I vaguely remember youtube's policy prohibiting anyone from having apps play YT videos in the background, have you checked that?

Comment: Just now ,what you say is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's only to youtube red users possible to play youtube videos in background ([see here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6308116?hl=en)). You can check if they have this in the api, but I don't think so.

Also it is possible to play youtube videos in background if you open the desktop version of youtube in a browser. Maybe you can make use of this by opening the correct link in a webview in background ;-) ...